# Do Mahavakyas and World as Illusion in Advaita contradict each other?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, upanishads

Chandogya Upanishad 3.14.1 says

> All this is Brahman. Everything comes from Brahman, everything goes
> back to Brahman, and everything is sustained by Brahman. One should
> therefore quietly meditate on Brahman. Each person has a mind of his
> own. What a person wills in his present life, he becomes when he
> leaves this world. One should bear this in mind and meditate
> accordingly.

Whereas Nirmalamba Upanishad and Vivekacudamani verse 20 say "ब्रह्म सत्यं जगन्मिथ्या जीवो ब्रह्मैव नापरः"

Do these 2 statements contradict each other??

Comment: Where did you get this translation of the Chandogya? You need to quote your source. It is not an accurate translation.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Please stop downvoting Questions sir. If you don't like then please don't write. Close it. Why Downvote and reduce my points??

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda How do you know its not an accurate translation?
See the source here : https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-english/d/doc239005.html
Translation by Swami Lokeswarananda
There was nothing wrong in my question. Why are you downvoting it??Please dont sir my request to you

Comment: Sir your question is not clear. Brahman is everything. Jagat is mithya. The world is nothing but Brahman. It is perceived wrongly as a snake but the underlying rope of Brahman is real. Mahavakyas only say that Atman and Brahman are same.

Comment: You should also quote Nirmalamba Upanishad and Vivekacudamani verse 20.

Comment: [It was written by adi Shankara.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivekachudamani)  I doubt it is shruti.

Comment: @DarkKnight I did quote them Minor Upanishads dont have verse numbers sometimes. Vivekacudamani isnt Shruti. Its a text written by an Acharya

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru it is a non dualistic monism interpretation of vedas and upanishades that are shruti. It is more like a poetic way of expressing your interpretation.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru and you explain what you find controdictry.

Comment: World is illusion for a brahmgyani, but real for an animal or extrovert common man, and sometimes real or unreal for sadhak, depending on his/her efforts to surpass Maya. Hence different people, depending on their stage, explain one Brahman differently, as its whole.

Comment: @DarkKnight Everything is Brahman and Jagat is Mithya and only self is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything including the world is Brahman. The upanishad you quoted also says the same thing. **All this is Brahman.**" Thus there is no contradiction.

According to advaita, the world is also Brahman but is perceived wrongly by the  ajnani. The ajnani thinks the world is real apart from Brahman but the substratum is Brahman. Take the example of bracelet, ring and necklace. The jnani sees the gold in each of them but the ajnani thinks each of them are different due to different names and forms. Advaita says the names and forms are not real by itself but dependent on the underlying substratum. The world of names and forms are not real by itself but dependent on Brahman, the underlying substratum.

> **ataH pR^itha~N.hnAsti jagatparAtmanaH*
>
> *pR^ithak.hpratItistu mR^iShA guNAdivat . guNAhivat*
>
> *aaropitasyAsti kimarthavattA.*
>
> *a-dhiShThAnamAbhAti tathA bhrameNa .. 235.. Vivekachudamani**
>
> The world has no existence apart from the Supreme Self and the
> appearance of its separateness is false like the appearance of a snake
> in a rope. Can a superimposition have any existence apart from its own
> substratum? Through delusion, it is the substratum itself which
> appears like that.

An ajnani perceives the world to be apart from the Brahman and real. But actually the world is Brahman only.

*Talk 399, Talks with Ramana Maharshi*

> Now they say that the world is unreal. Of what degree of unreality is
> it? Is it like that of a son of a barren mother or a flower in the
> sky, mere words without any reference to facts? Whereas the world is a
> fact and not a mere word. The answer is that it is a superimposition
> on the one Reality, like the appearance of a snake on a coiled rope
> seen in dim light. But here too the wrong identity ceases as soon as
> the friend points out that it is a rope.

> Whereas in the matter of the
> world it persists even after it is known to be unreal. How is that?
> Again the appearance of water in a mirage persists even after the
> knowledge of the mirage is recognised. So it is with the world. Though
> knowing it to be unreal, it continues to manifest. But the water of
> the mirage is not sought to satisfy one’s thirst. As soon as one knows
> that it is a mirage, one gives it up as useless and does not run after
> it for procuring water.

Answer (score 1):

No. Here confusion cause by interpretation of word Mithya as 'Asatya'.

From Sringeri Jagadguru's teaching from Link
[Question and answer series 5](https://youtu.be/jJ_-9xlCiws)

> There are some people with possibly vested interests , out there to defame the postulates of Advaita and necessarily create an element of hatred and aversion to it .

> This is detestable. It is of importance to understand correctly what the actual technical philosophical term" Mithya" means.Ignoracne , or  Improper or half baked knowledge or even intellectual dishonesty could be the reason for misunderstanding this term .

> Advaita does not assert that the world is unreal totally . It supports the reality of world like Dvaita and other philosophies too . This is very evident . But the point of difference lies in to what extent the reality is assigned . Reality of the world is temporary. It elides upon the dawn of Knowledge . The world is the creation of Maya . As discussed elaborately in previous episodes , Maya is an apparent pseudo-entity who veils the truth of Brahman . So world being its product(effect) falls under the reign and control of Maya(the cause) . When Maya is destroyed , so is the world . Being a product of Maya , the world also shares the property of being opposed to Knowledge of the Brahman . Hence when Brahman is revealed through Brahma -Jnana , the world must necessarily disappear for the Seer . This is the ontology of world as per Advaita . This is the meaning of the term  Mithya -temporary reality .

For full translation refer [samskrta Nandini](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwu74BQetfISxIiI_d5dWNw) user in comment section of this episode.